# Number of ways to place $k\cdot n$ labelled balls into $k$ unlabeled urns.

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we place $k\cdot n$ labelled balls into $k$ unlabeled urns such that each urn contains exactly $n$ balls?

According to me the result is $$\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{kn-in}{n}}{k!}$$

Can someone verify if I am correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your formula is correct
$$\frac{1}{k!}\binom{kn}{n}\binom{kn-n}{n}\binom{kn-2n}{n}...\binom{kn-n(k-1)}{n}=\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{kn-in}{n}$$